# Strange form behaviour inserting extra HTML

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

We are seeing a strange issue, on page load we get extra html inserted around a form submit button. Once the button has been clicked and #element_validate has been fired then the form displays correctly with the expected html output.

[image: Extra html, displays incorrectly with extra Go text]
[image: Expected form look]

**On page load** (extra html coded added around the submit button):

```
<form action="/" method="post" id="quality-banner-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="actionlink" value="node/283">
        <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-postcode">
            <label for="edit-postcode">Postcode <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
            <input placeholder="Postcode" type="text" id="edit-postcode" name="postcode" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text required uniform-input text">
        </div>

        <div class="button" id="uniform-edit-submit--2" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">
            <span>
                Go <input type="submit" id="edit-submit--2" name="op" value="Go" class="form-submit">
            </span>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-irh9tTAy3p22e2ZobcjpbZcG8MSctgdUI4nqzR4XlcA">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="quality_banner_form">
    </div>
</form>
```

**On element_validate** (correct html):

```
<form action="/" method="post" id="quality-banner-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="actionlink" value="node/283">
        <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-postcode">
            <label for="edit-postcode">Postcode <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
            <input placeholder="Postcode" type="text" id="edit-postcode" name="postcode" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text required error uniform-input text">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" id="edit-submit--3" name="op" value="Go" class="form-submit form-submit-updates">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-6sZ3K4c1L0ub4tc70A8vD3liiPFBXhjxdRFhwtTu-SQ">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="quality_banner_form">
    </div>
</form>
```

In our DEV environment the extra HTML is not seen and the form displays as expected on page load as well as on submit. We have compared both environments module and template files and they are identical.

Is there something we're missing or anything else we can check to see where the extra html is coming from?

Please let me know if there is any other info required that might help diagnose this issue. Bare with us, I'm a .NET developer.

Module file:

```
function quality_banner_form($form, &$form_state, $actionLink = '')
{
    $pc = @$_REQUEST['postcode'];
    if (!$pc) {
        $pc = @$_SESSION['postcode'];
    }

    $form['actionlink'] = array(
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#value' => $actionLink
    );

    $form['postcode'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Postcode',
        '#required' => true,
        '#default_value' => $pc,
        '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => 'Postcode'),
        '#element_validate' => array('_quality_validatePostcode')
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Go'
    );

    return $form;
}

function _quality_validatePostcode($element, &$form_state, $form)
{
    if (!preg_match('/[a-z0-9]{2,4} ?[a-z0-9]{2,4}/i', $element['#value'])) {
        form_error($element, t('Invalid postcode'));
    }
}

function quality_banner_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
    if ($form_state['values']['postcode']) {
        $_SESSION['postcode'] = $form_state['values']['postcode'];
    }
    drupal_goto($form_state['values']['actionlink']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to my limited knowledge of Drupal and time constraints; I 'solved' the issue by adding a new css rule.

```
#quality-banner-form div.button span input.form-submit[type="submit"] {
    border:none;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px 10px;
    margin:4px 0 0 0;
    background-color:#588c14;
    font-size:14px;
    font-size:1.4rem;
    line-height:1.2em;
}

#quality-banner-form div.button span {
    background: none;
    color: #71A330;
}
```

I would still like to know where the extra HTML is generated if anyone has an idea, please let us know.

Comment: Update: QA seems to work (as in no extra html is generated) after modifying the css file, loading site and then reverting back to original unmodified css?!  Strange behaviour but worked on both QA servers.